# Recommended Mac SQLite IDEs?

Tags: macos, sqlite, ide

Are there any free Mac OSX IDEs for SQLite that you would recommend?  I've seen some answers on SO from 2009 and 2010, but nothing recent.  If the SQLite manager for Firefox is still the one to go with, great, I'll try it.  I was just wondering if something else has come along since then that people like more.  There's nothing specific I'm looking for in terms of capabilities, just a tool that's as reliable, user friendly, and as full featured as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically I use Firefox plus the [SQLite Manager Extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/).

Comment: +1 on SqlLite FF plugin

I tried a few other ones like http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/ and http://sqlitestudio.one.pl/index.rvt?act=download, but the FF plugin is still the best

Answer (score 1):

Not free, but I use Navicat Premium as a front end for MySQL, Postgres, SQlite, MS SQL, Oracle.

I have a real love/hate relationship wiht Navicat - it's full featured and generally works well, but the doesn't adhere well to Mac UI standards.

Hope that helps, at least a little.