# Best Viewer for SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

What is the best SQLite browser?  Are there any tools like phpmyadmin for SQLite?

I am working in a C# project and I need a way to easily import/export sample data.  Most of the standard Managers such as Sqlite2009 don't seem to be able to edit table structures.

Comment: [SQLite Manager for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844625/recommended-mac-sqlite-ides/9844678#9844678

Comment: pro-tip: never ask a question on SO with "best [something]" in the title